# How to pass req.body from router file to module?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to separate my code into modules so the main files (app and router) stay relatively neat. The webpage accepts a POST from form and returns the user a PDF generated with user input.

In router.js I want to separate what's in the {} of the `if` blocks into separate files (in the first block I commented it out). However, when I do that, the separate file doesn't receieve the body info from the middle-ware (I get `ReferenceError: req is not defined`).

How can I export the {} of the if blocks (which will get very verbose, and there will be many more if blocks, which is why example1.js is in a folder pdfGenerators) into separate files so router.js stays clean?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<form method="post" action="sendPDF">
  <input name="userInput" type="text">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="example1">Send Example 1</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="sendPDF">
  <input name="userInput" type="text">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="example2">Send Example 2</button>
</form>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");    
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//server started?
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log('Started on PORT 3000');
  })
//For local testing only, using nginx normally
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), {
    extensions: ['html']
}))

//sendPDF routing
require('./router')(app);
```

router.js

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/sendPDF', (req, res) => {

        if (req.body.submit =='example1') {
            require('./pdfGenerators/example1')();
            /*const doc = new PDFDocument();

            doc.text(req.body.userInput);

            // Pipe its output as http response
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Example 1.pdf');
            doc.pipe(res);
            doc.end();*/
        }

        if (req.body.submit =='example2') {
            const doc = new PDFDocument();

            doc.text(req.body.userInput);

            // Pipe its output as http response
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Example 2.pdf');
            doc.pipe(res);
            doc.end();
        }
    })
};
```

example1.js

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
module.exports = function () {
const doc = new PDFDocument();

doc.text(req.body.userInput);

// Pipe its output as http response
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Example 1.pdf');
doc.pipe(res);
doc.end();

};
```

By the way, am I thinking in the right direction or do I have my architecture logic messed up, and is this an efficient way to generate such pdfs with pdfkit or will it cause problems with multiple simultaneous users?

Comment: example1.js shouldn't be handling req or res its job is to load or make a pdf file, you could export a custom render or generate function that accepts params to generate then it returns the doc then do all the response stuff in the controller.. separations of concerns, also dont repeat many lines of code to simply change a filename

Comment: I agree on keeping the response headers in the router file (and not repeating code). But, to generate the pdf example1.js needs access to req.body so it can't avoid that particular aspect, or is there another approach I can't think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function arguments as a way to expose `req` and `res` objects to `example1` module.

In your router,

```js
const PDFGenerator = require('./pdfGenerators/example1');
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/sendPDF', (req, res) => {

        if (req.body.submit =='example1') {
            PDFGenerator(req, res);
        }
        // ...
}
```

And then in your PDFGeneraor example1 module, you need to accept these parameters.

```js
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    //...
}
```